# How to generate several files in C

Tags: c, file

I want to generate 60 files, program0.txt,.., program59.txt. 
How can I do this?

My attempt:

```
FILE *fp[60];

for(i=0;i<60;i++){

   fp[i]=fopen("program.txt","w");

   fprintf(fp[i],"zeros=[");
}
```

Comment: Fix the file name and don't forget to close the file after you're done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use following `filename[]` to [form](http://rextester.com/ZGZBX73084) filenames

```
char filename[15] ;
int i;
for( i =0; i<60; ++i )
{
    sprintf(filename, "program%02d.txt",i);
    //printf("%s\n", filename );
   /*
    fp[i] = fopen( filename ,"w");
    ....
    fclose( fp[i] );

   */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

snprintf can be used to form a file name.

```
int main ()
{
     int i =0;
     char str [1024];

    for(i=0;i<60;i++){
        snprintf (str, sizeof (str), "/home/test/file_%d.txt", i );
        printf ("%s\n", str);
        if ( NULL == fopen(str,"w"))
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to use fclose() or you leak resources.

Comment: the OP was using the current directory, so the above works fine, except that the files are being placed in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is how to generate file names with indexes. You can use `sprintf` for each `i`:

```
char file_name[20];
sprintf(file_name, "program%d.txt", i);
```